# Are there W3C specifications for line wrapping behavior in an HTML <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, w3c, word-wrap

I'm working on a project to generate an image that replicates user-entered text input in a `<textarea>`. The best approach I've found is to read the `<textarea>`'s value and draw it on a `<canvas>`, from which I can read a blob and save to a file.

Here is a very naive example, just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

https://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/wmbMVq

Note that when the text that you enter in the `<textarea>` exceeds the length of the first line, the text in the `<textarea>` wraps, but the text on the `<canvas>` does not. That's the crux of the code that I still need to write, but first I need to fully understand `<textarea>`'s line wrapping behavior so that I can recreate it with a JavaScript algorithm.

By playing around with a `<textarea>` in Google Chrome, I've determined some basic behavior when a word exceeds the line width (as set by the rendered width of the `<textarea>`):

- Words that are preceded by a space will wrap, and the width of the preceding space is not factored into the rendered width of the previous line.
- Words that are hyphenated with a figure dash (‒, U+2012), en dash (–, U+2013), or em dash (—, U+2014) will wrap after the last hyphen that fits on the current line. I'm still exploring if there are other characters that hyphenate.
- Words that exceed the total line width will be broken mid-word, with subsequent characters overflowing to the next line(s).

However, experience tells me that there are likely to be some edge cases and cross-browser functional differences that I haven't considered. I searched for specifications that describe how exactly `<textarea>`s should wrap text, but I haven't found any. The closest I've gotten is the [spec for the `wrap` attribute](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-textarea-element.html#attr-textarea-wrap), but it doesn't offer much help.

Is this behavior just dictated by different rendering engines (i.e., not W3C-specified), or am I just missing the W3C specification? If the former, what behavior have I missed, and what do I need to be aware of in terms of cross-browser functional differences?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but another idea is not to use a textarea, but use a DIV with the contenteditable attribute,.  You could then maybe use something like https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to render to your canvas.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the suggestion! That is definitely worth exploring. My current understanding is that `contenteditable` still has many cross-browser gotchas, but I haven't actually tried it yet. Things may have gotten much better in recent years. My browser support baseline is IE11, FWIW.